# How do T cells deal with the obstructions in their path of migration?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, immunology, immune-system

When T cells move in the blood, are their any obstructions(other cells) while they migrate? If there are then how do the T cells overcome such obstructions in their path? Do they move past them or does their movement lead to displacement of the obstructions?

Comment: You might want to look this up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leukocyte_extravasation

Comment: @Polisetty thats a wonderful article you have shared. I did not know this had a term. Thanks a lot!